# Как реализовать появления текста вслед за движением объекта?

Tags: html, css, html5, svg, анимация

оригинал вопроса : https://toster.ru/q/525769
Примечание: вопрос удален модератором на toster.ru

Как всегда вопрос заинтересовал меня своей необычностью, приложу макет
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Начал с `SVG` и получилось это :

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg width="400px" height="400px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<title>Red Hot Chilli Peppers Logo</title>
<defs>
<path id="a" d="m243.2 382.4c-74.8 0-135.5-60.7-135.5-135.5s60.7-135.5 135.5-135.5 135.5 60.7 135.5 135.5-60.7 135.5-135.5 135.5z"/>
<style>text { 
 font-size: 16px;
 font-family: helvetica;
 font-weight: 900; 
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 17px;
 }</style>
</defs>
<text dy="20" textLength="1200">
<textPath xlink:href="#a">Red Hot Chilli Peppers</textPath>
</text>
</svg>
```

Как добиться  эффекта постепенного появления текста, изображенного на картинках в начале вопроса ?

Comment: отличный вопрос! Задавай такие вопросы почаще, которые вдохновляют.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Короткий ответ

Эффект  появления надписи достигается с помощью трех слоев:

- Статичный текст, который расположен вдоль `path` полуокружности
- Сверху для маскирования текста, расположен патч со цветом фона
- Анимированная маска, которая стирает маскирующий патч
  Плюс цветная окружность, которая движется вместе с маской

```css
text { 
 font-size: 18px;
 font-family: serif;
 font-weight: 900; 
 text-transform: uppercase; 
fill:#535353; 
 }
 .container {
 width:50%;
 height:50%;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  viewBox="0 0 400 400" >
  <defs>
  <mask id="mask1" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <path  fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-width="35" stroke-dasharray="393" stroke-dashoffset="393" d="M 100, 200  m -75, 0  a 75,75 0 1,1 250,0" >
   <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" dur="5s" values="0;-393" fill="freeze" /> 
   </path>
  </mask>
  <path id="Crc" fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-width="30"  d="M 100, 200  m -75, 0  a 75,75 0 1,1 250,0" />
    <filter id="hole-blur" x="-20%" y="-20%" width="180%" height="180%" >
      <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="5">
     <animate  attributeName="stdDeviation" dur="1.25s" values="2;5;5;5;3;2" repeatCount="indefinite" />
  </feGaussianBlur>
 </filter>
  </defs>
  <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/1REYQ.png" transform="translate(0 10)" width="300px" height="300px" />
   <text dy="0" textLength="100%" letter-spacing="4.8" >
<textPath xlink:href="#Crc"   startOffset="0%" >S o l u t i o n s  &  c o n s u l t
 </textPath>  
 </text> 
  <path class="clef dot"   d="M 100, 200  m -75, 0  a 75,75 0 1,1 250,0" stroke="white" stroke-width="35" mask="url(#mask1)" >
  </path>
   <circle cx="0" cy="3" r="12" fill="#00F1F5" filter="url(#hole-blur)" >
 <animateMotion
   id="an" dur="5s"
   repeatCount="1"
   rotate="auto-reverse"
   begin="0s"
   fill="freeze"
   restart="whenNotActive">
   <mpath xlink:href="#Crc"/>
</animateMotion>
</circle> 
</svg> 
</div>
```

### Подробно

- Текст расположен вдоль `path` полуокружности

```
     <text dy="0" textLength="100%" letter-spacing="4.8" >
    <textPath xlink:href="#Crc"   startOffset="0%" >S o l u t i o n s  &  c o n s u l t  </textPath>
```

Для кроссбраузерного решения пришлось искать варианты, чтобы заполнение и расстояние между буквами было одинаково: `textLength="100%" letter-spacing="4.8"`

- Сверху для маскирования текста, расположен `path` со цветом фона

```
 <path id="Crc" fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-width="30"  d="M 100, 200  m -75, 0  a 75,75 0 1,1 250,0" />`
```

Патч имеет форму дуги в половину окружности и его ширина `stroke-width="30"` полностью перекрывает текст

- Анимированная маска, которая стирает маскирующий патч

```
 <mask id="mask1" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <path  fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-width="35" stroke-dasharray="393" stroke-dashoffset="393" d="M 100, 200  m -75, 0  a 75,75 0 1,1 250,0" >
      <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" dur="5s" values="0;-393" fill="freeze" /> 
      </path>
  </mask>
```

Маска имеет ту же  форму `path`, что и маскирующий `path`, атрибут маски `stroke="white"` делает прозрачным маскирующий `path`. Анимационный эффект движения маски достигается изменением атрибута `stroke-dashoffset`

- Цветная окружность, которая движется вместе с маской

Движется по тому же пути, что и маска. Эффект размытия тени - фильтр Гаусса

```
 <filter id="hole-blur" x="-20%" y="-20%" width="180%" height="180%" >
      <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="5">
     <animate  attributeName="stdDeviation" dur="1.25s" values="2;5;5;5;3;2" repeatCount="indefinite" />
     </feGaussianBlur>
    </filter>
```

Анимация увеличения, уменьшения размытия окружности достигается изменением атрибута `stdDeviation`

1. Пример работает во всех современных браузерах, кроме `IE`, который по определению не умеет работать с анимацией.
2. Пример адаптивен
3. Можно создавать подобные приложения для своих проектов, меняя только текст и картинку.

[DEMO LIVE](https://codepen.io/Alexandr_T/pen/bMBRaM)

### Пример с другой картинкой

Изменен текст и понадобилось подогнать размеры картинки и её позиционирование

```
<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zUoo.png" transform="translate(20 85)" width="250px" height="250px" />
```

```css
text { 
 font-size: 18px;
 font-family: serif;
 font-weight: 900; 
 text-transform: uppercase; 
fill:black; 
 }
 .container {
 width:50%;
 height:50%;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  viewBox="0 0 400 400" >
  <defs>
  <mask id="mask1" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <path  fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-width="35" stroke-dasharray="393" stroke-dashoffset="393" d="M 100, 200  m -75, 0  a 75,75 0 1,1 250,0" >
   <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" dur="5s" values="0;-393" fill="freeze" /> 
   </path>
  </mask>
  <path id="Crc" fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-width="30"  d="M 100, 200  m -75, 0  a 75,75 0 1,1 250,0" />
    <filter id="hole-blur" x="-20%" y="-20%" width="180%" height="180%" >
      <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="5">
     <animate  attributeName="stdDeviation" dur="1.25s" values="2;5;5;5;3;2" repeatCount="indefinite" />
  </feGaussianBlur>
 </filter>
  </defs>
  <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zUoo.png" transform="translate(20 85)" width="250px" height="250px" />
   <text dy="0" textLength="100%" letter-spacing="4.8" >
<textPath xlink:href="#Crc"   startOffset="0%" >Our club come &  c o n s u l t
 </textPath>  
 </text> 
  <path class="clef dot"   d="M 100, 200  m -75, 0  a 75,75 0 1,1 250,0" stroke="white" stroke-width="35" mask="url(#mask1)" >
  </path>
   <circle cx="0" cy="3" r="12" fill="#03ABF3" filter="url(#hole-blur)" >
 <animateMotion
   id="an"
   dur="5s"
   repeatCount="1"
   rotate="auto-reverse"
   begin="0s"
   fill="freeze"
   restart="whenNotActive">
     <mpath xlink:href="#Crc"/>
 </animateMotion>
</circle> 
</svg> 
</div>
```

Comment: Super..............